# XFOIL Package bug or my computer?

Tags: 20.04

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.1 and having a problem with the amd64 package of xfoil6.99.dfsg+1-1build1.

I feel like XFOIL was working fine, but recently when I try to run viscous simulations it crashes after converging. The error is (I included the last iteration for reference):

```
 Side 1  free  transition at x/c =  0.7345   25
 Side 2 forced transition at x/c =  1.0000   32

   6   rms: 0.1064E-04   max: -.1704E-03   C at   32  2

       a =  2.000      CL =  0.7139
      Cm = -0.1097     CD =  0.01011   =>   CDf =  0.00560    CDp =  0.00451
      9.000    7.1067   0.010107   0.003307   0.005186   0.001879    0.7345     #
At line 3071 of file ../src/xoper.f (unit = 44)

Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file ':00.bl': Invalid argument

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f53311b7cd1 in ???
#1  0x7f53311b8819 in ???
#2  0x7f53311b94ef in ???
#3  0x7f53313f58b6 in ???
#4  0x7f53313f5bac in ???
#5  0x560c9572a1f0 in ???
#6  0x560c9572d717 in ???
#7  0x560c957196be in ???
#8  0x560c9570f748 in ???
#9  0x7f5330e630b2 in ???
#10  0x560c9570f77d in ???
#11  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
```

I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it a couple of times but it did not help. I am not sure if this is a bug or something wrong on my end.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Interesting development... I downloaded the source code and built XFOIL 6.99 and got the same error, BUT the problem seems to only occur on an SSD I recently installed. I will try the XFOIL package again and see if it works okay not on that drive.

Comment: The reinstalled package works fine on my original drive, but not a drive I installed a few days ago. Kind of annoying but fortunately I have a work around.